# Change value attribute of element with specific name attribute

Tags: jquery

I want to change the value of a param element which has a specific name.
In this case the name attribute is 'filter' and it also has an attribute value which I want to change to the selected value 1 , 2 or 3.

```js
jQuery( document ).ready(function() {

  $('#list').on('change', function() {
  
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="list">
  <option value="" selected="selected" disabled="disabled">Options</option>
  <option value="1">Option 1</option>
  <option value="2">Option 2</option>
  <option value="3">Option 3</option>
</select>

<object class="paramList" width="939" height="945" style="display: none;">
  <param name="test" value="blabla" />
  <param name="okok" value="lalala" />
  <param name="filter" value="CHANGE"/>
</object>

<div class="result"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use attribute selector and use `attr()` function to access the value of the attribute. When you change your drop  down value, just change the value of your param with `$(this).val()`.

```js
jQuery( document ).ready(function() {
  $('#list').on('change', function() {
    $('.paramList param[name="filter"]').attr('value', $(this).val());
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="list">
  <option value="" selected="selected" disabled="disabled">Options</option>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
</select>

<object class="paramList" width="939" height="945" style="display: none;">
  <param name="test" value="blabla" />
  <param name="okok" value="lalala" />
  <param name="filter" value="CHANGE"/>
</object>

<div class="result"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use attribute selector
`$('param[name=filter]');`
and combine it with
`$('#list').find(":selected").text();`

```
      $('param[name=filter]').attr('value', $('#list').find(":selected").text())
```

EDIT:
JS fiddle for you
https://jsfiddle.net/3vcwmt4m/

it set selected value to the param with choosen name :)

What is more, you could find elements with some masks i.e.

```
$('td[name^=filter]') // objects those names begins with 'filter'

$('td[name$=filter]') // objects those names ends with 'filter'

$('td[name*=filter]') // objects those names contains 'filter'
```